# Are Premium Success Plans per user or per company?

Tags: licenses, support

Our organizations plans on starting up with Salesforce and we were thinking of buying the Premium Success+ Plan.

Is it **per company**?

If it's **per user**, does a company need as many of these plans as many users there are? Or it is useful only for Admin/Developer/etc users?

I know it is not just about the support and there's a lot of training-related opportunity in there but let's suppose not everyone is interested in the training.

Comment: i believe it is per org although your cost may be based on number of users. You can also negotiate and possibly get a limited number of live courses per year. You will need to contact your AE for details specific to your account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support plans (and sandboxes also) are provisioned on a 1:1 basis with an organization's licenses.

So if you have 10 licenses then a specific plan is calculated at a certain percentage of the list price of the 10 licenses. Each additional license you may add in the future will include the base price based on the edition plus the plan cost on top of it.

Sandbox prices are derived the same way.

At the time of writing this, Premier Success+ plan is calculated at 75%, and Full Sandbox is calculated at 30% of the list price of all licenses.